# Why is different username on a question I asked in newest listing? (Mobile version)

Tags: bug

Few minutes back I asked a question on stack overflow, here: [Scrapy start_urls request returns 503, how to catch it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704321/scrapy-start-urls-request-returns-503-how-to-catch-it)

When I now searched for it from mobile version of the site, I discovered that there is someone's else username in a listing. There is no answer from the user, nor edit or comment. So why is he there? Is that a bug?

[image][image][image]

Comment: They posted an answer and deleted it.